# Send Email Through ASP.Net Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms

I am attempting to pass parameters to an asp.net webpage and as soon as the page loads take those parameters and pass them to an email and have the email send.
My page loads fine, my email sends fine, but it seems the parameters are being lost somewhere along the way (or maybe not even actually being passed).
Could someone with some more knowledge on this matter assist me?

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    String userID = Request.QueryString["userID"];
    String employeename = Request.QueryString["employeename"];
    String jobsite = Request.QueryString["jobsite"];

    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("aspTest14871112@gmail.com");
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("diditwork@gmail.com"));
    msg.Subject = "Test Email From AsP.NET";
    msg.Body = userID + " " + employeename + " " + jobsite;
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient(sSMTPServer);
    c.Send(msg);
}
```

Actual site going to with attempting to pass parameters:

> http://www.internalwebsite/testing/autogenerate.aspx?userID=TOSTRING(userID)&employeename=employeename&jobsite=jobsite

Comment: use smtp port as well. 25 and 489

Comment: @PankajGupta He said the email was sending fine, so let's not tell him to change something that's already working.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code and see what values you're getting.

Comment: What is TOSTRING(userID)? Do you really pass something that intends to be like a function embed?

Comment: @MaximilianoRios - it is converting an int value to a string value

Comment: No any of the values is passed?

Comment: Please set a breakpoint and evaluate the arguments passed in the query string like @mason suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that if you changed TOSTRING(userID) to userID.ToString(), you would get the values.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to be honest. He said PARAMETERS are being lost not just this one. The question is wrong if this is the correct answer.